Sitecore Powershell Layout Delta
I'm trying to figure out how to obtain the delta between the Shared Layout and Final Layout. I have a component in the Shared Layout, but not in the Final Layout, but it is still not showing on the rendered page. Is there a way to find this out using SPE?

Is it on multiple pages or just one page?

The component also does not show in preview or edit mode?

@SumitUpadhyay it's on several pages, a component disappeared but is still in the Shared Layout field.

This PowerShell script may help you troubleshoot the issue. However, I suspect that it will merely point out what you already know and that your actual issue may be related, but not limited to, any of the following:

Rendering error (runtime / compilation)
Publishing
Versioning
Language
Conditional logic
Personalization

$itemPath = "/sitecore/content/CHANGE_ME"
$item = Get-Item -Path $itemPath

Write-Host "Checking renderings for $itemPath..."

$sharedLayout = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.LayoutField]$item.Fields["__Renderings"]
$sharedXml = $sharedLayout.Value

$finalLayout = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.LayoutField]$item.Versions.GetLatestVersion().Fields["__Renderings"]
$finalXml = $finalLayout.Value

$emptyLayoutXMLFallback = "<r />"

if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($sharedXml)) {
    Write-Host "Shared Layout is empty / null"
    $sharedXml = $emptyLayoutXMLFallback
}
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($finalXml)) {
    Write-Host "Final Layout is empty / null"
    $finalXml = $emptyLayoutXMLFallback
}

$sharedDoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$sharedDoc.LoadXml($sharedXml)

$finalDoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$finalDoc.LoadXml($finalXml)

$sharedRenderings = $sharedDoc.SelectNodes("//r[@uid]")
$finalRenderings = $finalDoc.SelectNodes("//r[@uid]")

$sharedSet = @{}
foreach ($r in $sharedRenderings) { $sharedSet[$r.Attributes["uid"].Value] = $r.OuterXml }

$finalSet = @{}
foreach ($r in $finalRenderings) { $finalSet[$r.Attributes["uid"].Value] = $r.OuterXml }

$onlyInShared = $sharedSet.Keys | Where-Object { -not $finalSet.ContainsKey($_) }
$onlyInFinal = $finalSet.Keys | Where-Object { -not $sharedSet.ContainsKey($_) }

$areSharedAndFinalEqual = $onlyInShared.Count -eq 0 -and $onlyInFinal.Count -eq 0
if ($areSharedAndFinalEqual) {
    Write-Host "Shared Layout and Final Layout are the same."
} else {
    Write-Host "Components only in Shared Layout:"
    if ($onlyInShared.Count -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "None"
    } else {
        $onlyInShared | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
    }

    Write-Host "Components only in Final Layout:"
    if ($onlyInFinal.Count -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "None"
    } else {
        $onlyInFinal | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
    }
}

